# Changed /usr/share/nginx/html/ softlink, now nginx won't serve it @localhost

Tags: nginx

I use nginx (1.2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 desktop) to preview frontend designs I'm working on, and something unusual just started happening

The design I was working on was originally located in:

`~/Projects/Clients/ANS/src/MetroBusiness.ans`

That was softlinked to nginx's localhost directory:

`/usr/share/nginx/html/dev/MetroBusiness.ans`

And I could view the site at `http://localhost/dev/MetroBusiness.ans`.

But the problem started after I cleaned up my home directory structure and moved the src directory to ~/work:

`~/work/clients/ans/src/MetroBusiness.ans`

And [re-linked it in nginx's localhost directory](http://i.imgur.com/0zrOk.png):

`/usr/share/nginx/html/dev/MetroBusiness.ans`

But now I can't view the site in localhost.  It should be the same url, but now I'm getting:

`Welcome to nginx!  If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working.`

However, the other soft-linked sites that I didn't change still work fine, just the one I changed and re-linked.

Also, it doesn't show up [in the nginx directory listing](http://i.imgur.com/RGt9d.png) (with other sites linked in the same way, but not recently moved)

I made sure permissions were [set to `rwxrwxr_x`](http://i.imgur.com/1Q0HY.png) on the moved src directory with `chmod -R`, restarted nginx, even restarted the computer, but no luck.

I'm sure there's something minor I'm missing, but drawing a blank now.  Any idea why Nginx can't see this soft link anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen before and all I needed to do was delete the link and reset it again.

```
rm /usr/share/nginx/html/dev/MetroBusiness.ans
```

and then set it again:

```
ln -s ~/work/clients/ans/src/MetroBusiness.ans /usr/share/nginx/html/dev/MetroBusiness.ans
```

and check if you were successful:

```
ls -l /usr/share/nginx/html/dev/
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck.  Have tried that already, but also tried copy and pasting your code exactly, but still same issue.  Only thing I can think of is a permissions problem, but 1) I didn't change the permissions when I moved the directory in the first place, and 2) I made sure they were set exactly as the other working directories.  Baffled.

Comment: Maybe try to `chown` the file using the user that nginx is running as